# Suggestion for design a DataGridViewPager

Tags: c#, user-controls, c#-4.0

I want to design a DataGridViewPager control similar to Asp.Net DataPager with Linq 2 Sql.
I want to get Suggestions from experts that can help me.
I Consider that place a DataGridView property for pointing the appropriate DataGridView and an object for *box* list of classes(Database tables) to pass to my UI layer and than *Unbox* it to list of desirable Class.

how to tell control from witch method get desire list of information?

can any body explain about DataPager and guide me to create a better Control?
thanks